# Building a website on Top of Django-CMS or Mezzanine

Tags: django, content-management-system, django-cms

Is it possible to built my "Learning Management System (LMS)", on TOP of Content Management Systems like **Mezzanine** or **Django-CMS** ?

I'm building a product for a private **school**, and I found that the patterns are so close to a CMS, except for having my own models (Course, Subjects, etc.)...

There should be some learning curve to get the best result of a CMS, of course.

what do you recommend ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mezzanine has its own implementation of a page tree rather than using mptt, and it's quite solid. It's also designed for you to add your own Django models to the tree. From what you've said (which granted isn't much) it sounds quite suitable. Have a read over the relevant docs section here: http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just checked the "Content architecture", and "model architecture", and wonder if I can define Roles as well? Say, designing Admin, Student, Tutors,etc. based on their own specified responsibilities? For instance, Tutors can create a course and student are able to only add that course to their basket after enrollment? Admins have control over the whole system .

Answer (score 2):

I've not used mezzanine, but doing something like this would certainly be possible on top of django_cms.

It's quite straightforward to write custom plugins for a CMS, so you could build new widgets (assessments, polls etc) which can be dropped into cms-based pages. The menu's can also be extended , with new menus build based on objects in your models (e.g. courses, modules)... one gotcha with this is that the menus get cached, so the app either needs to be restarted to rebuild menus or you would have to add a hook to rebuild them manually. There are pretty good docs on this here:

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html

and on building custom apps, which can be hooked up to CMS urls:

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/extending_cms/app_integration.html

Overall, I quite like django_cms, although the breakage with successive versions (and also versions of MPTT on which it depends) has been quite a pain. It looks like they are trying to clean up this sort of thing in forthcoming releases though, and contrib.staticfiles is now supported which is nice.

Comment: MPTT is the exact thing which is necessary for designing the Course model. What's wrong with its implementation in Django-CMS ? would you please explain it a bit more ??